# Azure function activity in ADF V2 timeouts after 4min 7sec, even though in code i have mentioned "functionTimeout": "00:10:00" which is 10mins?

Tags: timeout, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-function-app, consumption

I have created an azure function and its timeout is set to 10mins in hosts.json but when I am triggering it through ADF V2 azure function activity then activity is getting terminated after 4mins 7sec, Can any one guide me what is happening at the backend and why I am getting this behavior? Thanks.

**Update: If i run my azure function through ADF or from postman it gives me this error after 4min 7sec:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        < !-- body {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: .7em;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: #EEEEEE;
        }

        fieldset {
            padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.4em;
            margin: 0;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 1.7em;
            margin: 0;
            color: #CC0000;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            color: #000000;
        }

        #header {
            width: 96%;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 6px 2% 6px 2%;
            font-family: "trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #555555;
        }

        #content {
            margin: 0 0 0 2%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .content-container {
            background: #FFF;
            width: 96%;
            margin-top: 8px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

        -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Server Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
                <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web
                    server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an
                    invalid response from the content server.</h3>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**And if I go to App insights of function App it shows me timeout of 10mins which I think is correct because I am using consumption plan so I know that. But at 4min and 7sec the 502 response which is sent to the client i am not familier with issue.** Please guide.

Comment: Hi Bilal, you can go to your function to see the log by yourself first. If still can't find the cause, please provide more details.

Comment: @HuryShen, Thanks for replying. I am updating my question with further details.

Comment: May I know if this error happen every time ? Or just happen occasionally ?

Comment: This is happening everytime. Let me clear again, the client either it is ADF or Postman it is returned this error "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." in 4min 7sec. While my function app continues to run as expected. And terminates after 10mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function can continue to run as expected even though the 502 error shows, so I think it has nothing to do with your azure function.

As far as I know, azure function activity just allows 230 seconds for the request in data factory. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity?ocid=AID754288#timeout-and-long-running-functions).
[image]

If you want to request it by postman, you can set the "request time out" in the "settings" of your postman. Please refer to this [document](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/launching-postman/settings/).

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: hmm, I know about that timeout which is 230secs but in my case either in ADF or in postman (with Request timeout in ms set to 0) I am getting this 502 error.

Comment: Hi @BilalShafqat, could you please remove all of the code in your function and replace it with "Thread.Sleep(250000);". And then test it in postman, check if it will response 502 error when it comes 4min 7s.

Comment: Yup, you were right. I have used durable functions to achieve this use case due to limitation of 230 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just me, but if true that you are limited to 230 seconds then this is CRAZY. I can definitely run functions for longer than that. In consumption plan up to 10 minutes, in premium plan you can have 60 minutes run time. [See here](https://build5nines.com/azure-functions-extend-execution-timeout-past-5-minutes/).
If the answer is to use Durable function, then you might as well just implement your workflow in there and forget about ADF completely.
Azure Function ADF Activity tool-tip states that default timeout is 12 hours.
Something doesn't smell right.